# PayPal ACH transfer?

Tags: c#, .net, paypal, payment-gateway

I am on working on one project which needs PayPal ACH support. Could you please let me know how can I do ACH transaction using PayPal?

I am referring this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/152280/Online-Credit-Card-Transaction-in-ASP-NET-Using-Pa

It is using PayFlow SDK and does credit card transfer. I can do the same for ACH. But bigger problem is the code is not using any PayPal secret / key. How does a person know the money would be transferred in his account?

Please let me know the appropriate link where I can search for ACH request using PayPal in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using PayPal as your processor they don't offer direct ACH.  The PayFlow Gateway does have parameters for it, but that's only if you're using some other company as your processor and they offer it.

PayPal's equivalent to ACH is an actual PayPal payment where the person chooses their bank account as the funding source.

As for the credentials you asked about, PayFlow doesn't use the secret key like the REST API does.  Instead, it uses the same credentials that you use to login to your manager.paypal.com account.  Then you can create separate users for API access only within your account if you want to, and use those within your calls.  So the credentials in a PayFlow request are actually USER, PASS, VENDOR, PARTNER.